# Redirect URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have old URLs in my site and looks like this

```
http://www.example.com/forum/index.php/topic/
```

I want to redirect it to

```
http://'www.example.com/forum/index.php?/topic/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/forum/index\.php(/.+) /forum/index.php?$1
```